# "Mage registry key already exists" when firing events

Tags: events, magento, registry

I'm Currently trying to hook into the "sales_order_save_after" event, but I constantly get the following error when the event is fired:

```
Mage registry key "_singleton/Modulename/Orderobserver" already exists
```

Now I've checked that the Orderobserver class is named correctly, and matches up with the call to the class in the xml, but the error is still occuring. The xml calling the event looks as so:

```
<events>
    <sales_order_save_after>
        <observers>
            <modulename>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>Modulename/Orderobserver</class>
                <method>generateOrderFile</method>
            </modulename>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_save_after>
  </events>
```

the class is named `Companyname_Modulename_Model_Modulename_Orderobserver`.

The class file is named and located as so: `app/code/local/Companyname/Modulename/Model/Modulename/Orderobserver.php`

Interestingly, the following error is also logged  in the server logs when the error occurs:

```
client denied by server configuration: 
/var/www/vhosts/path/to/subdomain/httpdocs/app/etc/local.xml
```

Could this be a permissions issue?

Update:

I've looked in the Magento system Log, and the following error is also being logged:

```
Failed opening 'Mage/Retailpro/Model/Orderobserver.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/path/to/subdomain/httpdocs/app/code/local:/var/www/path/to/subdomain/httpdocs/app/code/community:/var/www/path/to/subdomain/httpdocs/app/code/core:/var/www/path/to/subdomain/httpdocs/lib:.:')  in /var/www/path/to/subdomain/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Comment: The client denied by server configuration is unrelated.  Magento has an internal check that attempts to request local.xml via HTTP, and if it's accessible it bails for security reasons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, although it's probably not neccesay, change this

```
<class>Modulename/Orderobserver</class>
```

to

```
<class>modulename/orderobserver</class>
```

Convention on class aliases is they're all lowercase.

Second, the class alias `modulename/orderobserver` translates to a class name of

```
Packagename_Modulename_Model_Orderobserver
```

So you've named your class file wrong.  Finally, since Magento's autoloader is based on class name, that means your file needs to be located at

```
app/code/local/Packagename/Modulename/Model/Orderobserver.php
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made all the changes you suggested, but I still have the same result. Looking at the error report in the magento system.log, it states `failed opening 'Mage/Modulename/Model/Orderobserver.php'`. Would this suggest that it's looking in the Mage Folder and not the Companyname folder. Could this be the root of the issue?

Comment: That's correct.  If your custom module's config.xml setup for models?

Comment: Ah, good question. I'm currently copying from a module the developer before me at this company wrote, and I only copied the bits from the xml that I thought were relevant. I just added a bit of xml, and it works fine now. Thanks for your help, you're a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

You will receive this error if < events > is inside < global >

Move it to either < frontend >< event > or < adminhtml >< event > outside of the < global > tag to fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
<global>
    <models>
        <newitems>
            <class>Microtron_Newitems_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>newitems_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </newitems>
        <newitems_mysql4>
            <class>Microtron_Newitems_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>        
                <newitems>
                    <table>newitems</table>
                </newitems>
            </entities>
        </newitems_mysql4>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <newitems_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Microtron_Newitems</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </newitems_setup>
        <newitems_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </newitems_write>
        <newitems_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </newitems_read>
    </resources>
    <events>     
        <catalog_product_save_after>      
            <observers>     
                <newitems>     
                    <type>singleton</type>  
                    <class>newitems/observer</class>   
                    <method>catalog_product_save</method>  
                </newitems> 
            </observers>  
        </catalog_product_save_after> 
    </events>
</global>
```

Comment: You should describe <model>  section